# localStorage having null value on SECOND REFRESH

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Kindly, Do not mark it as duplicate as I have already check the matching question but problem is different.
I am using Vue and Inside it I am setting local storage on some condition as I will explain in code afterwards.
When I refresh page I get value in console as it should be working but if I refresh second time then it shows null

My Function

```
data:{
age:'',

},
methods:{
getAge:function()
{

axios.get('/getage').then((res)=>{
this.age = res.data;

if(localStorage.getItem('age')===null)
{
localStorage.setItem('age',this.age)
}

})


},
mounted(){
console.log(localStorage.getItem('age'));
}
```

So What happens is When the first time I get Age and refresh the page I get age successfully in console but If I again refresh page without calling getAge function it shows null.

Before you say that as function wasn't called it is showing null I would like to add that it is local Storage so If once some value is set it must have it unless or until removed

Comment: print `this.age` . I think it is null in second refresh and you are setting it as null

Comment: I have printed it and it is holding previous in short yes it is null but how it became null i set it when function was called shouldn't it be present?

Comment: Anywhere else you call getAge or setItem() ?

Comment: Consider improve the code formatting. Bad formatted code takes more time to read, and may cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
data:{
  age:'',
},
methods:{
getAge:function() {
  axios.get('/getage').then((res)=>{
    this.age = res.data;
    if(localStorage.getItem('age')===null) {
      localStorage.setItem('age',this.age)
    }
  })
 }
},
mounted(){
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('age'));
}
```

It seems that the mounted property is inside on methods property. You need to close } methods property

Comment: It is same as in question

Comment: You need to close the method getAge(), please, try to add a brace } , before closing methods property

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough posted to answer this question. It's open to speculation only... If you provide more info I can adjust my answer.

One problem here is that `getAge` isn't being called at all in this segment. So `mounted` is the first thing to be called, which gets whatever was already in `localStorage`. With the limited info provided, I'd say the most likely cause is that your endpoint is returning null. So on first refresh, the value you see is whatever is already in your `localStorage`. Then `localStorage` is updated to null. Then when you refresh, you are printing the null value that was previously stored in `localStorage`. But to be honest, that's a wild guess, because there just isn't enough information here to debug this, and I can think of at least three other potential causes off the top of my head.

It's important to know how to troubleshoot these types of problems for yourself. Most browsers have a developer tools window that you can pop up. In Chrome you can do this by hitting F12. Go to the application tab and you can actually see what's in `localStorage`. You can print to console each step of the way to see where the code is executing. You can add `debug` statements in your code as breakpoints and see what's going on. You can use dev tools to inspect network traffic to see what the endpoint is passing back. If `localStorage` is really volatile for you, you should be able to reproduce that in a very simple situation. If you can, then it's probably a problem with an extension. If you can't, it's probably a problem with your code, or with a polyfill (or some other part of your app or its dependencies). This is 100% something that you should be able to narrow down before posting to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling a function on app start
Functionality of that function was to reset the localStorage()
I Missed that function and posted this question.
I hope you'll forgive me